# Making links like clicable blocks

Tags: html, css

I am building a menu. I have this code:

```
 <nav>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="novy2.html">Kontakt</a></li>
          <li><a href="novy2.html">Reference</a></li>
          <li><a href="novy2.html">Moje služby</a></li>
          <li><a href="novy2.html">Kdo jsem</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
```

And CSS:

```
    nav{
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
border-top: 3px solid red;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
background-color: white;
}


nav li{
float: right;
padding: 20px 35px 0 0px;
}

nav ul{
margin-right: 100px;
height: 90px;
list-style-type: none;
}


nav a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: Montserrat;
font-weight: 700;
}


nav a:hover{
text-align: center;
color: 33adae;
```

What I am trying to do is to make the links clickable like blocks with the height of the whole navbar. The way I have done It so far, you can click only the text in the links.

Comment: could you describe what you mean by blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally all that is needed is.

```
nav a{
display:block;
}
```

However for a fuller example it's generally easier to let the links determine the height of the header.

For centering, don't use floats, set the `ul` to `text-align:center` and the `li` to `display:inline-block`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  ;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* clearfix */
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-align: center;
  color: 33adae;
  background: plum;
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Kontakt</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Reference</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Moje služby</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Kdo jsem</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the links to be 100% of the height of the `nav` element too.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the padding from your `li`s and add it to your `a` tags. See example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaGxpb

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @Paulie_D It does answer the question in the first line. The link is only for reference. Please explain if I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Move your `<li>` padding to the `<a>` children, and give the links a height:

See **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xmeabq)**

NB: Added a *border* to the links so as you see the boundaries.

Comment: and how to set the height of the link to 90px, as the whole navbar and center it??

Answer (score 0):

display the links as blocks `display: block;` and use the `line-height` to give them the height you want. Try this:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
}
nav li {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 35px 0 0px;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0 100px 0 0;
  height: 90px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-weight: 700;
}
nav a:hover {
  text-align: center;
  color: 33adae;
```

```html
<nav>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Reference</a></li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Moje služby</a></li>
    <li><a href="novy2.html">Kdo jsem</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version using height and with properties instead of padding, i used background colors so you can see how is working: http://codepen.io/aluknot/pen/wKrqaG

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="novy2.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a href="novy2.html">Reference</a></li>
        <li><a href="novy2.html">Moje služby</a></li>
        <li><a href="novy2.html">Kdo jsem</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    border-top: 3px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
}

nav li{
    float: right;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 90px
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: green;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;  
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

nav a:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```